# How can I emulate internet explorer for multiple versions with c# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

I want to emulate internet explorer for multiple versions with c# selenium, is it even possible? How can I do that? I made some test cases and I want to run them on IE 8,9,10,11. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this depending how you set up yours tests.

I believe the easiest way to do this is something along the lines of:

```
public void StartUpIE(string version){
    string path = @"..\..\..\Drivers\IE\32\" + version;
    //Rest of code to create an instance of IE as you would
}
```

Then in your test:

```
[Testmethod]
public void testIE (){
    StartUpIE("11");
    //Do some testing
    StartUpIE("11.1");
}
```

Comment: Have you used selenium before? My answer was fairly straight forward and I'm struggling to explain what to do further without having to cover selenium aswell.

Comment: `Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"..\..\..\IE\32\" + version)` It is not working.

Comment: Can you copy the full code of the testing class and the class you use to start and instance of your browser?